# Jetty 9 - redirect http to https

Tags: ssl, http, redirect, https, jetty

I'd like to force use of https in Jetty 9. Apparently:

```
<Set name="confidentialPort">443</Set>
```

no longer works in jetty 9. How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

This [resource](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL) says to add this to your web.xml

```
<web-app>
  ...
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Everything in the webapp</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```